# Commutative diagrams side by side

Tags: tikz-cd, sidebyside

I would like to set these diagrams side by side. Any help would be appreciated.

```
{\Large$$
\begin{tikzcd}
X\arrow{r}{i}\arrow[swap]{dr}{j} & M \arrow{d}{j'}\\
& N
\end{tikzcd}
$$}
```

and

```
{\Large$$
\begin{tikzcd}
X\arrow{r}{j}\arrow[swap]{dr}{i} & N \arrow{d}{i'}\\
& M
\end{tikzcd}
$$}
```

Comment: Note that you should use `\[...\]` instead of `$$...$$`. [Details here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/125871).

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you mean?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
X\arrow{r}{i}\arrow[swap]{dr}{j} & M \arrow{d}{j'}\\
& N
\end{tikzcd}\hspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzcd}
X\arrow{r}{j}\arrow[swap]{dr}{i} & N \arrow{d}{i'}\\
& M
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Fine. It works.

Answer (score 3):

If you really insist on `\Large` (but you shouldn't), define your own environment. And it's better to use the “modern” syntax for arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newsavebox{\tikzcdbox}
\newenvironment{Largetikzcd}
 {\begin{lrbox}{\tikzcdbox}\Large\begin{tikzcd}}
 {\end{tikzcd}\end{lrbox}\usebox{\tikzcdbox}}
  

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{Largetikzcd}
X \arrow[r,"i"] \arrow[dr,swap,"j"] & M \arrow[d,"j'"] \\
& N
\end{Largetikzcd}
\qquad
\begin{Largetikzcd}
X \arrow[r,"j"] \arrow[dr,swap,"i"] & N \arrow[d,"i'"] \\
& M
\end{Largetikzcd}
\]

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
X \arrow[r,"i"] \arrow[dr,swap,"j"] & M \arrow[d,"j'"] \\
& N
\end{tikzcd}
\qquad
\begin{tikzcd}
X \arrow[r,"j"] \arrow[dr,swap,"i"] & N \arrow[d,"i'"] \\
& M
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Never use `$$` in a LaTeX `document` environment.